# Codeigniter Insert Multiple Fields Using Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multiple-insert

I have a problem when I want to insert multiple fields which are using foreach loop (to get the value form database), here is my form:

```
<form class="stdform" action="<?php echo $action_url; ?>" method="post">

    <label>Check Date</label> <input class="span3" type="text"
        id="datepicker" name="check_date" value="" required="required"
        placeholder="Tanggal cek" />

    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered"
        style="font-size: 12;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="head0">#</th>
                <th class="head0">Device</th>
                <th class="head0">IP Address</th>
                <th class="head0">NAT IP Address</th>
                <th class="head0">Check OS</th>
                <th class="head0">Application/Server</th>
                <th class="head0">Shift A</th>
                <th class="head0">Shift B</th>
                <th class="head0">Remark</th>
                <th class="head0">Report</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Row Template -->
            <?php 
                        $num=1;
                        foreach( $get_server_assets as $row ) {

                         ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $num; ?>
                </td>
                <td><input class="span12" type="text" name="device[]"
                    value="<?php echo $row->s_device; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input class="span9" type="text" name="ip_address[]"
                    value="<?php echo $row->s_ip; ?>" /></td>
                <td><input class="span9" type="text" name="nat_ip[]"
                    value="<?php echo $row->s_nat_ip; ?>" /></td>
                <td><select class="span12" name="check_os[]">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Good">Good</option>
                        <option value="Not Good">Not Good</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input class="span10" type="text" name="app_name[]"
                    value="<?php echo $row->app_server; ?>" /></td>
                <td><select class="span12" name="check_app_a[]">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Good">Good</option>
                        <option value="Not Good">Not Good</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><select class="span12" name="check_app_b[]">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Good">Good</option>
                        <option value="Not Good">Not Good</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input class="span12" type="text" name="remark[]" value="" /></td>
                <td><input class="span12" type="text" name="report[]" value="" /></td>
            </tr>

            <?php $num++; } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p class="stdformbutton">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" name="submit"
            value="true">Submit</button>
        &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-large" onclick="window.history.back()">Cancel</a>

    </p>

</form>
```

And here is my controller:

```
$data = array();

        $count = count($this->input->post('device'));

        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

            $data[] = array(
                'check_date'=>$this->input->post('check_date'),
                'device'=>$this->input->post('device' . $i),
                'ip_address'=>$this->input->post('ip_address' . $i),
                'nat_ip'=>$this->input->post('nat_ip' . $i),
                'check_os'=>$this->input->post('check_os' . $i),
                'app_name'=>$this->input->post('app_name' . $i),
                'check_app_a'=>$this->input->post('check_app_a' . $i),
                'check_app_b'=>$this->input->post('check_app_b' . $i),
                'remark'=>$this->input->post('remark' . $i),
                'report'=>$this->input->post('report' . $i),
            );

        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('server_checklist',$data);

        /*foreach($_POST['data'] as $d) {

            $this->db->insert('server_checklist',$d);

        } */

        redirect('admin/viewServerChecklist');
```

When I submit there is no data insert, only check_date stored. And the rest give value 0.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGPej.png)

Can someone help me??

Comment: why are you adding $i to each variable name? Isn't it an array so you will access it like  $this->input->post('check_os')[$i] ?

Comment: ah thanks @Silwerclaw Poor me, you can say this is my first time working with array things. Thanks a lot you're really helpful.

Comment: only one form , multiple rows, and you have to insert each row in to db??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju yes, one form with foreach loop (to get each row data value from server_assets table) and insert each row data into server_checklist table. Is that possible? Because I think it's possible (am I wrong? CMIIW )

Comment: check the answer, it mite help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$data_table = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

        if (empty($data_table['device']))
        {
            redirect('admin/viewServerChecklist?message=error');
        }

        $required = array('device', 'ip_address', 'nat_ip', 'check_os', 'app_name', 'check_app_a', 'check_app_b', 'remark', 'report');
        $data = array();

        foreach ($data_table['device'] as $key => $value) 
        {
            // check list table. if value required not exist. continue to next index
            $row = array();
            foreach ($required as $key2 => $value2) 
            {
                if (!isset($data_table[$value2][$key])) continue;
                $row[$value2] = $data_table[$value2][$key];
            }
            // since check_date is not array. we need to parse to row data
            $row['check_date'] = $data_table['check_date'];
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('server_checklist', $data);

        /*foreach($_POST['data'] as $d) {

            $this->db->insert('server_checklist',$d);

        } */

        redirect('admin/viewServerChecklist');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, instead of appending, try to access the index of the array.

```
  $data[] = array(
            'check_date'=>$this->input->post('check_date'),
            'device'=>$this->input->post('device')[$i],
            'ip_address'=>$this->input->post('ip_address')[$i],
            'nat_ip'=>$this->input->post('nat_ip')[$i],
            'check_os'=>$this->input->post('check_os')[$i],
            'app_name'=>$this->input->post('app_name')[$i],
            'check_app_a'=>$this->input->post('check_app_a')[$i],
            'check_app_b'=>$this->input->post('check_app_b')[$i],
            'remark'=>$this->input->post('remark' )[$i],
            'report'=>$this->input->post('report')[$i],
        );
```

Comment: I did it in my development server (local) and it works! But it didn't work in my production server (internet). It gives error, my browser turn all white and didn't return any error messages. Any advice?

Comment: add this line in constructor, `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I did error_reporting(E_ALL) at constructor, the result still same, didn't return any error msg.

Comment: I use CodeIgniter 2.2

Comment: is your controller class name starts with capital letter??

Comment: can you `print_R($this->input->post());` in beginning of your function??